# The required version of distribute (>=0.6.49) is not available?

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I tried to install the SoundCloud API using PIP (*pip install soundcloud*), to get this error message,

> Downloading/unpacking soundcloud   Running setup.py egg_info for
>   package soundcloud
>       The required version of distribute (>=0.6.49) is not available,
>       and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
>       install a more recent version first, using
>       'easy_install -U distribute'.
>
> ```
> (Currently using distribute 0.6.24dev-r0 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages))
> Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
> The required version of distribute (>=0.6.49) is not available,
> ```
>
> and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
>
> install a more recent version first, using
>
> 'easy_install -U distribute'.
>
> (Currently using distribute 0.6.24dev-r0
>   (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages))

I tried as reccomended, running **easy_install -U distribute**, to find this,

> error: can't create or remove files in install directory
>
> The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in
>   the installation directory:
>
> ```
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-1661.pth'
> ```
>
> The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix,
>   or the distutils default setting) was:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
> ```
>
> Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If
>   the installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need
>   to sign in as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have
>   administrative access to this machine, you may wish to choose a
>   different installation directory, preferably one that is listed in
>   your PYTHONPATH environment variable.
>
> For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
>   documentation at:
>
> http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html
>
> Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.

I tried going to the link at the bottom, to get a 404 message. What can I do to get everything back in order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running:

`sudo easy_install -U distribute`

`sudo` allows you to run commands as the 'root' user to access files and directories your regular user account may not have access to.